# How to count the extracted elements?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to know the number of links that return in the extraction below:

```
for produtos in classeprodutos:
    link = produtos.find_element(By. TAG_NAME, "a")
    lista_link.append(print(link.get_attribute("href")))
```

Comment: Your `lista_link` will contain nothing but `None`s, because the `print` function does not return anything.  Remove the inline print and do it after the loop.  If you do that, then you can `print(len(lista_link))` after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call an iterable maeaning a list inside len() function to count the total number like:

```
print(len(classeprodutos))
```

#OR

```
lista_link = []
for produtos in classeprodutos:
    link = produtos.find_element(By. TAG_NAME, "a")
    lista_link.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

print(len(lista_link))
```